# Does a <header> have to be at the top of an element?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have a `<nav>` element where its title is wrapped in a `<header>`. However, this `<header>` is the *last* element in the `<nav>`. **Is this a good practice?**

I looked at the W3C's definition of `<header>`, and it has this to say:

> The `header` element represents introductory content for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element. A `header` typically contains a group of introductory or navigational aids.
>
> When the nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element is the body element, then it applies to the whole page.

This doesn't explicitly say where in its nearest ancestor it should be placed, but implies it should be the first (or topmost) element.

---

Here's a screenshot of my current mockup:

[image: A navigational element stuck to the top of the webpage, with the title at the bottom]

Note that this is not the final design and the element is `position: fixed` to the top of the viewport

Comment: Can you post an image of how it looks?

Comment: I would think the element name "header" implies the position, since it comes from "head" which is synonymous with "top" given its biological position on a human. If it appears at the bottom, then [`<footer>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/footer) might make more sense, but I concur that an image would probably help in this particular case.

Comment: Interestingly, while it does say "Footers don't necessarily have to appear at the *end* of a section, though they usually do.", it does not say anything about headers necessarily appearing at the start of a section. (Then again, that's probably why this question was asked.)

Comment: @Supuhstar In that case your setup is perfectly fine

Comment: Goodness... do _all_ my my posts get close votes?

Comment: @BoltClock - In HTML5, `<header>` and `<footer>` are not really complements of one another. I much prefer the WAI-ARIA term "contentinfo" to "footer", because it makes it much clearer that block can go anywhere sensible in its section. `<header>` on the other hand is for *introductory* content. While it need not be the top most element, introductory content is there to "set the scene" for the principal content of section, and therefore would only ever make sense if it preceded that principal content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the standard it doesn't say you cant do this. It only says the header element cant be a decendant of an address or footer element. So go for it.

header - http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/header.html

nav - http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/nav.html

Generally speaking it would make sense for the nav element to be a child of the header element, or for the two to be separate.